# Boids particles loop seamlessly

Tags: particles

I am trying to create a school of fish swimming around and looping seamlessly, but I cannot loop the particles because (I think) it is impossible to control the particles following the leader location.

Is there any way of making boids particles loops seamlessly?
I have tried everything I could think of, but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: i don't think that is possible because boids itself use lots of randomness....and changing just one parameter will change the whole simulation. If you really want a loop, you have to fake that manually ...i think...